# how to get the dictionary with a given value in a list of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary, for example my given key value is 'jerry'.

Is there a way to loop to the list and return only dictionary with the key value name of 'jerry'?

```
lst= [{'name':'tom','score':5},{'name':'jerry','score':10},{'name':'jason','score':8}]
```

It should return

```
{'name':'jerry','score':10}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all suitable elements with a generator expression and pick the first with `next`:

```
next(d for d in lst if d['name'] == 'jerry')
```

Comment: `d.get('name')` is better if the key may be missing

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
result = [x for x in lst if x['name'] == 'jerry'][0]
```

As a side note, you may want to use a `namedtuple` for your data if you're going to have a lot of similarly structured dictionaries and you don't want to mutate them:

```
Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'name score')
lst = [Person('jerry', 10), ...]
result = [x for x in lst if x.name == 'jerry'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension should work:

```
lst = [{'name':'tom','score':5},{'name':'jerry','score':10},{'name':'jason','score':8}]
print([d for d in lst if d['name'] == 'jerry'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also use [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) method

```
lst = [{'name':'tom','score':5},{'name':'jerry','score':10},{'name':'jason','score':8}]
filter(lambda x: x.get('name') == 'jerry', lst)
```

OR create lambda:

```
getUserDataByName = lambda userName: filter(lambda x: x.get('name') == userName, lst)
```

OR:

```
getData = lambda propName, propVal: filter(lambda x: x.get(propName) == propVal, lst)
```